# How to select and replace HTML attributes in string using regex and PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to change

```
{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class="open-sans" style="font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;" >FORM TITLE</h3>"}
```

to this ( replace double quote for HTML attributes with single quote )

```
{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class='open-sans' style='font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;' >FORM TITLE</h3>"}
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is that a json string?

Comment: Yes, it's a broken one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaaaand the answer is:

```
$count = null;
$subject = '{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class="open-sans" style="font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;" >FORM TITLE</h3>"}';
$result = preg_replace('/="(.*?)"/s', '=\'$1\'', $subject, -1, $count);
print_r(htmlspecialchars($subject) . "<br />");
print_r(htmlspecialchars($result));
```

Outputs:

```
{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class="open-sans" style="font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;" >FORM TITLE</h3>"}
{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class='open-sans' style='font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;' >FORM TITLE</h3>"}
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5g33-8k4f

Alternative solution without regex (a bit ugly, but might be easier to understand for newcomers):

```
$string = '{"name":"column","content":"<h3 class="open-sans" style="font-size: 2em; line-height:2em;" >FORM TITLE</h3>"}';
$array = explode('="', $string);
array_shift($array);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $temp = explode('"', $value);
    $search = '"' . $temp[0] . '"';
    $replace = "'" . $temp[0] . "'";
    $string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
print_r(htmlspecialchars($string));
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ksqm-gu1r

Comment: You are welcome. Please click on the "tick" next to the upvote button to accept my answer. :)